# Showing two inequalities are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, inequality

In *Graphs and Digraphs* by Chartrand and Lesniak, a proof of a generalized Turan's Theorem uses the following fact: the inequalities $r \leq n \leq 2(r-1)$ are equivalent to the inequality

$$\binom{r-1}{2} + (n-r+1)(r-2) + \binom{n-r+1}{2} \leq \frac{r-2}{2r-2}\cdot n^2$$

Where $\binom{n}{k}$ is the binomial coefficient $n$ choose $k$, and $n, r$ are positive integers such that $r\geq 3$.

Why is this single inequality is equivalent to $r\leq n \leq 2(r-1)$?

I've tried multiplying out and simplifying, but that leaves a mess that doesn't obviously lead to anything. I've tried using the fact that $r \leq n \leq 2(r-1)$ exactly when $(n - r)(n - 2(r-1)) \leq 0$ (this is just a quadratic in $n$), but no luck there either.

Multiplying out the large inequality and bringing all terms to the left yields:

$$n^2 + 2r^2 - 4r - 3nr + 3n + 2 \leq 0$$

However when we multiply out the quadratic $(n - r)(n - 2(r-1)) \leq 0$, we get

$$n^2 + 2r^2 - 2r -3nr + 2n$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I've tried multiplying out and simplifying, but that leaves a mess that doesn't obviously lead to anything."?  (EG Show what you've tried)  I got a nice expression, though it's not equivalent to $r \leq n \leq 2(r-1)$ (though it is close). $\quad$ Also, I think you're assuming that $n > 0, r > 1$, and maybe even that these are integers? If so, you should state that clearly.

Comment: @CalvinLin, I've added all the things you've requested.

Comment: Note that your expression factorizes as $(n-2r+2)(n-r+1)$. That is what I got too (after multiplying by $r-1$).

Comment: @CalvinLin Right, so it should be equivalent to $r - 1 \leq n \leq 2(r-1)$. In the context of the proof, this is good enough to use (although misleading as stated).